# Remove colored frame around doi in revtex

Tags: hyperref, color, revtex, doi

In this MWE, I obtain light-blue (cyan?) borders around the doi despite all options to `hyperref` and `\hypersetup`.

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0},allbordercolors={0 0 0}}
\begin{document}
    \doi{100.200/300.400}
\end{document}
```

How can I get rid of this border without redefining the `\doi` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, never mind. I found the answer browsing though `revtex4-1.cls`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\pdfstartlink@attr{}
\makeatother
```

In the preamble, after selecting the `documentclass`, helps.